# TSV file converts string into numbers

Tags: c#, csv, formatting, cell

I'm creating tsv export file from database information.

From database I receive string like "012345678901234567823456789012347890123" but in generated tsc file I can see "1.23456789012346E".

This isn't correct cause it shouldn't be number.

Is it possible to tell tsv parse column as string, not as number?

---

```
private static string BuildTagsRow(IEnumerable<string> tags)
{
   var tagsRowString = string.Join("\t", tags);

   return tagsRowString;
}
```

This is part which generates tsv row based on input collection. Later this returned string is written as new line to StreamWriter (`streamWriter.WriteLine(line);`)

Comment: How are you viewing the file? In Excel?

Comment: @Equalsk LibreOffice Calc

Comment: I'm not familiar with Calc, but I assume the same as Excel that it just interprets this as a number and displays it as so, if you opened the file with something more basic such as Notepad it'd be a plain string.

Comment: @Equalsk, well, yes, you are right... with Notepad it looks correct :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need that a number should be interpreted as text in Excel you can prepend the field content with a simple quote `'` Like `'5468`

I think that Calc will have similar behaviour